# New Dalaran Quest Line

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What is the name of the quest that takes you to New Dalaran in WoW? Or who do I talk to in WoW to get to New Dalaran? I have a level 100 Hunter that has never been to the Broken Isles or Dalaran. I am desperately trying to get him there. TY in advance for your help.

Comment: Btw.. if you completed the quest chain at least once you can skip it with your other characters and go to Broken Shore's Dalaran right away.

Answer (score 1):

You have to complete a series of quests to witness the dalaran moving from "icecrown to Deadwind pass then finally to broken island".

The first quest is named "The legion return" regardless of which faction you are in (alliance vs horde). The link below will have more step by step instructions.

Source: http://www.wowhead.com/guides/starting-legion-questing#broken-shore